# Check if multi-word command output starts with a certain string in bash

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I am trying to check if a multi-word command output starts with a certain string. For example, here I am trying to check the default Python version. Here is my current code that does not work:

```
# handle default python version
pycmd="python"
if [[ "$($pycmd --version)" = "Python 2"* ]]
then
  echo "It is Python 2"
  pycmd="python3"
else
  echo "It is Python 3"
fi
```

What can I do to achieve my goal (i.e., checking the default Python version and change `$pycmd` if needed.) The above code always goes to the `else` block even if I change the string to `"Python 3"*`. Also, I don't want to print the output of the Python version command.

Comment: Probably the version is written to `stderr`. Replace the `$($pycmd --version)` with `$($pycmd --version 2>&1)`

Comment: @M.NejatAydin It works with your proposed change!